# Weird behaviour of argument repetitions in Rust macro

Tags: rust

Faced a weird case of repeated argument mismatch while creating a macro in Rust:

```
use std::mem;

trait Object {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct This {}
impl Object for This {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct That {}
impl Object for That {}

macro_rules! types {
    ($($fname:ident),*) => {
        enum Type {
            $($fname),*
        }

        fn match_it(t: Type, b: Box<Object>) {
            let p = match t {
                $(
                Type::$fname => {
                    mem::transmute::<Box<Object>, Box<$fname>>(b)
                }
                ),*
            };
        }
    }
}

types!(This, That);

fn main() {}
```

It results in:

```
error: match arms have incompatible types [--explain E0308]
  --> <anon>:20:21
20 |>             let p = match t {
   |>                     ^ expected struct `This`, found struct `That`
<anon>:31:1: 31:20: note: in this expansion of types! (defined in <anon>)
note: expected type `Box<This>`
note:    found type `Box<That>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> <anon>:22:33
22 |>                 Type::$fname => {
   |>                                 ^
<anon>:31:1: 31:20: note: in this expansion of types! (defined in <anon>)
```

Shouldn't the $fname of enum be the same as $fname of Box if they share the same loop?

[Play it.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=630f5a84dd70f9b25aac5a43c9389f03&version=stable&backtrace=2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro expands to something like:

```
enum Type {This, That }

fn match_it(t: Type, b: Box<Object>) {
    let p = match t {
        Type::This => mem::transmute::<Box<Object>, Box<This>>(b),
        Type::That => mem::transmute::<Box<Object>, Box<That>>(b),
    }
}
```

What's the type of `p`?  Depending on something at runtime, the compile-time type must be different; this doesn't make sense in a statically typed language like Rust.

I suggest looking into [`std::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html), which seems similar to what you might be trying to do.

Comment: In addition: those transmutes are *absolutely wrong* anyway.  Rust is not Java: you *cannot* transmute between `Box<ConcreteType>` and `Box<Trait>` like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, both Any's (core & mopa) can be used only for T or &T (please correct me if I'm wrong), but not for Box<T> and any other complex type like Arc<RwLock<RefCell<Box<T>>>>. Plus in my original task (above is super-simplified sample) I need to know the type of the stuff coming as arg. If it's not possible, I consider trying splitting match_it to several versions for each concrete type. Too bad I need concat_idents working for this, but it's still unusable at the moment.

Comment: I use `Box<Any>`.  Could you describe what you're trying to achieve? The question doesn't say *what* you're trying to do, only a solution you've tried that didn't work. What do you want to do with the `Box<This>` or `Box<That>`?

Comment: Dependency Injection.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b9eda7c6cf3469411f63a369fcc7e6b3&version=nightly&backtrace=2

Comment: To workaround these transmutes I need to know the exact type of the argument. Runtime type casting is not possible, so I'm trying to mimic it with macros.

Comment: I'm afraid there's too much code and macros for me to work out which bit is important, but I've added an answer showing how the runtime type casting works.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, maybe you want runtime casting using `Box<Any>`:

```
use std::any::Any;

struct N(isize);
struct S(String);

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<Any>> = Vec::new();

    v.push(Box::new(N(17)));
    v.push(Box::new(S("foo".to_string())));

    let s = v.pop().unwrap().downcast::<S>().unwrap();
    let n = v.pop().unwrap().downcast::<N>().unwrap();
    println!("Extracted {} and {}", s.0, n.0);
}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0be2c01d47069308c9aab3bf56760e46&version=stable&backtrace=2)

Comment: Thanks. But I accepted your first answer as correct cause it describes why macros cannot be used to mimic dynamic typing. Still need to cast not the trait itself, but its synchronized and refcell'ed copy.

Comment: One small but important change, and this example fails. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4b498a3fc4363fb555b5293e283e66cc&version=stable&backtrace=2

Comment: @snuk182 You do have to use `Box<Any>`, not `Box<T>`, even if `T: Any`.  This is because `Box<Any>` is slightly special, and if you look at [the Box documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html), `downcast` it says `impl Box<Any+'static> ...`, not the more generic `impl<T> Box<T:Any>` there.